# Why TextMesh Pro in unity not working after it is instantiated?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have created a prefab containing a model and textmesh pro.

I have added certain effects like outline to TEXTMESH PRO.After making sufficient changes I made it as prefab(Model + TextMeshpro).When I instantiate the prefab the model comes and the text comes but without any effects.All the changes I made in the prefab are gone,this is when I test using the play button in unity editor.After stopping the unity editor when I drag my prefab into the hierarchy,the Textmesh pro has all the changes I made and is working fine.So my question is after instantiating the Textmesh pro will not work?

Comment: It works well..

Comment: Cant say ive had this issue either, is it not showing in runtime in the editor or after build?

Comment: I have added a new font now no probs it is working....It wont work with the default font?

Comment: TMP is very strange thing, try to restart the editor - sometimes it helps. And always apply changes to the prefabs

Comment: @caxapexac I too got that feeling may b after sometime or restarting might have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

it's been a while since this was asked but I came across this issue too and just found my answer. I open of the prefab editor thing and saw that all my effects to the text were gone, you need to add them in there for it to apply after you've instantiated.